# Define a relation $M$ on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$...

Tags: relations

**Update #2  (7.21.15):**

Here is a screenshot of the corrected question, in case anyone was interested.

[image]

No need to look at the first update or original post to anyone viewing this for the first time.

Mia

---

**Update #1    (07.19.15):**

Sorry about the confusion. This was exactly as the problem was presented to me-- I reached out to stackexchange because I was seriously confused on what she was asking me to do. Seems as though the confusion was warranted... so... yay math?

Here is the problem I am working on:

---

Define a relation, $M$, on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ by $(x_1,y_1) M (x_2,y_2)$ if and only if $x_1 \mid x_2$ and $y_1 \mid y_2$ is even.

Prove or disprove that $M$ is each reflexive, symmetric, transitive, and/or antisymmetric.

---

This is the problem, as it has been presented to me. I am curious about how to best approach this. Here is what I am thinking so far:

$M= \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}\mid x-y \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$

Does this make sense as the start towards my relation? I don't feel like I've addressed the even portion of my problem, which is where I find myself stuck. If $x_1 \mid x_2$ and $y_1 \mid y_2$ is even, then I can state that:

$x_1-x_2 = 2k, k \ \in \mathbb{Z}$ and,
$y_1-y_2 = 2j, j \ \in \mathbb{Z}$

But I'm not really sure where to work this into my relation. Suggestions or hints would be appreciated!

Once I get the relation worked out, I think I can figure out the reflexive, symmetric (etc.) portion of the problem.

Update: here is a screen shot of the problem.

[image]

---

Comment: What do you mean by $x|y$?

Comment: What does it mean that "$y_1\mid y_2$ is even"? Usually "$y_1\mid y_2$" is a proposition -- it can be true or false, but not even or odd.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I don't have $x \mid y$, so I'm not sure to what you are referring.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't believe that $y_1 \mid y_2$ has to be a proposition. This is parameter set by how I should come up with a relation.

Comment: @mia.avery: You can define the notation to mean something that is not a proposition if you want to. But then you need to **tell us what your new meaning for that notation is**, if you want us to answer questions about it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  It means "divides". Sorry, this is the standard notation used in my text book, I didn't realize this would be perceived as unknown or "new" notation.

Comment: @mia.avery: Yes, usually it means "divides", but "$y_1$ divides $y_2$" is a claim that can be true or false, not a number that can be odd or even. So with that meaning of $y_1|y_2$, your definition of $M$ does not make sense.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So, I have written the problem exactly as it was presented to me. I do not know how to solve it, I do not know how to properly develop my relation, $M$- this is what I am asking for help with. I do not realize why my question/post is unclear. Sorry...?

Comment: @mia.avery: You will need to ask the people who gave you the problem what it means. It is not using standard mathematical terminology -- neither "$y_1$ divides $y_2$ is even" nor "$y_1|y_2$ is even" makes any sense in common mathematical English. Was it translated from some other language?

Comment: @mia.avery It's unlikely that that's exactly how the problem was presented, because it doesn't make sense.  Try taking a picture of the problem and adding that to your question.

Comment: You wrote that "$x_1$ divides $x_2$ is even" means that $x_1-x_2=2k, k \in \Bbb Z$, or $x_1\equiv x_2 \!\pmod{2}$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @ChrisCulter I attached the problem. So, unless I suck at transcribing...

Comment: @HenningMakholm No... she wrote the question herself, and she has English as a first language. This certainly explains why I'm confused... ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for uploading the screen shot! Now it's clear that the author of the problem made a mistake somewhere. You could try to guess what they meant, but if possible, it would be better to notify them of the mistake and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. This certainly explains why I was seriously confused on how to solve this problem... didn't mean to cause MathStack drama, but I seriously couldn't figure out what to do with this thing. Guess I'll go ask my professor... (she wrote this question, so I dunno what she was thinking).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "is even" is a typo, and M is defined by

$$(x_1,y_1)M(x_2,y_2) \Leftrightarrow x_1|x_2 \ \text{and}\ y_1|y_2$$

- You can see that $M$ is reflexive :

$x|x$ and $y|y$ so $(x,y) M(x,y)$

- You can see that $M$ is transitive :

if $x_1|x_2$ and $x_2|x_3$ , then $x_1|x_3$

- You can see that $M$ is **not** symetric :

You have $(1,1)M(2,3)$ but not $(2,3)M(1,1)$ as $2\nmid 1$

- You can see that $M$ is **not** antisymetric :

$(-1,-1)M(1,1)$ and $(1,1)M(-1,-1)$ but $(-1,-1) \neq (1,1)$